# Essential Container in task exited in ECS

Tags: node.js, mongoose, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I am trying to set up ecs.I have created repository, cluster, and task while running task am getting an error as an essential container in task exited

here is the error message

```
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  node:internal/process/promises:279  NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);  NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  ^   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017  NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:847:32)    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:351:10   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5 NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at new Promise (<anonymous>)    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at promiseOrCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1149:10)    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Mongoose.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:350:20)    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/server.js:12:10)    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10) NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)  NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  reason: TopologyDescription {   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  type: 'Single', NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  setName: null,  NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  maxSetVersion: null,    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  maxElectionId: null,    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  servers: Map(1) {   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  address: 'localhost:27017', NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017  NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) { NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  name: 'MongoNetworkError'   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  },  NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  roundTripTime: -1,  NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  lastUpdateTime: 166070, NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  lastWriteDate: null,    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  opTime: null,   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  type: 'Unknown',    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  topologyVersion: undefined, NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  minWireVersion: 0,  NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  maxWireVersion: 0,  NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  hosts: [],  NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  passives: [],   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  arbiters: [],   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  tags: []    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  }   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  },  NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  stale: false,   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  compatible: true,   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  compatibilityError: null,   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null, NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  localThresholdMS: 15,   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  commonWireVersion: null NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  }   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  }   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  connection error: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:847:32)    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:351:10   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5 NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at new Promise (<anonymous>)    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at promiseOrCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1149:10)    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Mongoose.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:350:20)    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/server.js:12:10)    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10) NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)  NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  reason: TopologyDescription {   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  type: 'Single', NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  setName: null,  NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  maxSetVersion: null,    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  maxElectionId: null,    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  stale: false,   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  compatible: true,   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  compatibilityError: null,   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null, NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,    NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  localThresholdMS: 15,   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  commonWireVersion: null NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  }   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:34 am  }   NodeApp
21/4/2022, 12:54:04 am  Express app listening on port 8080  NodeApp
```

Added docker file

```
FROM node:16

# Create app directory WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+) COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080 CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

here is server.js

```
    const express = require('express'); const ejs = require('ejs'); const path = require('path'); const app = express(); const bodyParser
= require('body-parser'); const mongoose = require('mongoose'); const session = require('express-session'); const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

const MongoDBURI = process.env.MONGO_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/ManualAuth';

mongoose.connect(MongoDBURI, {   useUnifiedTopology: true,   useNewUrlParser: true });

const db = mongoose.connection; db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:')); db.once('open', ()
=> { });

app.use(session({   secret: 'work hard',   resave: true,   saveUninitialized: false,   store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: db   }) }));

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

const index = require('./routes/index'); app.use('/', index);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler app.use((req, res, next) => {   const err = new Error('File Not Found');   err.status = 404;   next(err); });

// error handler // define as the last app.use callback app.use((err, req, res, next) => {   res.status(err.status || 500);   res.send(err.message); });

// listen on port 3000 app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {   console.log('Express app listening on port 8080'); });
```

Not sure why am i getting this issue. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Do you also have MongoDB deployed in the same ECS task? It is saying it can't connect to MongoDB on port `27017`

Comment: Yes I created MongoDB task on the same VPC

Comment: @MarkB Do i have to update my server.js with the mongodb private IP

Comment: Yes, if they are running in separate tasks then 127.0.0.1 would obviously be the incorrect IP address, so you would have to update that. Ideally you would set it via environment variables instead of hard-coding it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Mark B for your suggestions.

Updated the server js file

Before

```
const MongoDBURI = process.env.MONGO_URI ||'mongodb://localhost/ManualAuth';
```

After

```
const MongoDBURI = process.env.MONGO_URI || 'mongodb://172.31.47.10:27017/ManualAuth';
```

172.31.47.10 is the private IP of the MongoDB in ECS